# Javascript, Creating a form from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Trying to read objects from array and place them in a form. I am new to Javascript and I am struggling to understand why this doesn't work. I have tried to look online for help but so far haven't found anything.

Here is my code so far:

```js
        var arr = [
            {Section: 1, Max: 20},
            {Section: 2, Max: 30},
            {Section: 3, Max: 50}
        ];

        var length = arr.length;

        function createForm() {
            for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
                form = document.getElementById("formed");
                var x = arr.Section[i];
                var y = arr.Max[i];
                form.appendChild(x);
                form.appendChild(y);

            }

        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body onload="createForm();">
<form id="formed">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't generate any HTML elements to add to the form. `.appendChild()` needs an HTML element to append. If you want to insert data, then you need to have an element to insert it into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use index `i` on array and not on object attributes, like :

```
var x = arr[i].Section;
var y = arr[i].Max;
```

Instead of :

```
var x = arr.Section[i];
var y = arr.Max[i];
```

Hope this helps.

**Sample snippet that generate `input`'s with values `x/y` from the object :**

```js
var arr = [
  {Section: 1, Max: 20},
  {Section: 2, Max: 30},
  {Section: 3, Max: 50}
];

var length = arr.length;

function createForm(){
  for (i in arr) {
    form = document.getElementById("formed");

    var x = arr[i].Section;
    var y = arr[i].Max;

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', x+' -- '+y)

    form.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="createForm();">
  <form id="formed"></form>
</body>
```

Comment: This still won't actually append any child elements to the form.

Comment: Yes because there's no HTML generation, but the main problem comes from those indexes. I've added a sample just to give it an idea..

Comment: Thank you for this! I understand where I was going wrong now. I was really struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you want to do but if you want to call the x element of an array you must do:

```
var array = ["mario","luca","paolo"];
print(array[0]); //will print "mario"
```

then you must do:

```
arr[i].Section;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.

**1. Condition within for loop:** The condition in the for loop is incorrect `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {` for loop should be running till the condition `i <length` otherwise you will reach the length of the array and will get undefined.

**2. Accessing Array Elements:** You need to access the array by the index.
So following needs to be changed to

`var x = arr.Section[i];
 var y = arr.Max[i];`

**To**

`var x = arr[i].Section;
var y = arr[i].Max;`

**3.Appending Nodes to DOM:** You can only add `Node` elements to the DOM. So, you can't write directly `form.appendChild(x);` but instead you need to create a `Node` object like `TextNode` by method on `document` object like `document.createTextNode(x)`

So, Change

`form.appendChild(x);
 form.appendChild(y);`

**To**

`var textnodex = document.createTextNode(x);
var textnodey = document.createTextNode(y );
form.appendChild(textnodex);
form.appendChild(textnodey);`

Following is the complete working version

```js
var arr = [
            {Section: 1, Max: 20},
            {Section: 2, Max: 30},
            {Section: 3, Max: 50}
        ];

        var length = arr.length;

        function createForm() {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var form = document.getElementById("formed");
                var x = arr[i].Section;
                var y = arr[i].Max;
                var textnodex = document.createTextNode(x);
                var textnodey = document.createTextNode(y);
                form.appendChild(textnodex);
                form.appendChild(textnodey);

            }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
</head>
<body onload="createForm();">

<form id="formed">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```